# Receiving different responses from tensorflow served model when sending identical Requests

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I created and trained a TensorFlow model, and now I want to use it for predictions. For that, I saved it and loaded it in a server, using TensorFlow Serving.

Once the server is up and ready to receive Requests, I send the same request 2 times, with enough time between them to let the model end the first prediction before starting the second.
I expect the 2 responses returned by the server to be the same, since it corresponds to the predictions made by the same model, on the same input. However, this is not the case.

Does anyone has already experienced the same issue, or knows by what it is cause ?

I tried :

- To change the tensorflow_model_server & tensorflow_serving_api version (2.1.0 & 2.4.1)
- To run the server on different machines
- To compare the Request objects sent to the server, just to be sure they are identical

But none of this solved my problem.

Also :

- I communicate with the server containing my model using gRPC
  Requests, and following the Step 5 of [this guide](https://towardsdatascience.com/serving-deep-learning-model-in-production-using-fast-and-efficient-grpc-6dfe94bf9234)
- Here is the return of the `saved_model_cli show --dir {path} --all`

:

```
MetaGraphDef with tag-set: 'serve' contains the following SignatureDefs:

signature_def['__saved_model_init_op']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['__saved_model_init_op'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INVALID
        shape: unknown_rank
        name: NoOp
  Method name is: 

signature_def['model_densenet_2D_new']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['input'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_UINT8
        shape: (-1, 512, 512, 1)
        name: model_densenet_2D_new_input:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['semantic_labels'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 512, 512, 2)
        name: StatefulPartitionedCall:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict

Defined Functions:
  Function Name: 'served_model'
    Option #1
      Callable with:
        Argument #1
          input: TensorSpec(shape=(None, 512, 512, 1), dtype=tf.uint8, name='input')
```

Comment: Tensorflow Serving uses Tensorflow to run the requests under the covers and Tensorflow does not guarantee deterministic results. Can you use saved_model_cli to run the same inputs to see if you get repeatable results?

Comment: Hello,
After some tests, the problem seems to come from tensorflow itself, and not tensorflow serving:
When I use saved_model_cli to run one input two times in a row, The ouputs i get are identical. 
But when I run saved_model_cli once, with a batch of identical inputs, each output are different.
This wouldn't bother me if the differences were small, But my model's output are probability values, and it can sometimes go from 0.1 to 0.8, with the same input considered.